# VkApi.wall().get() Вопрос

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Хочу вывести список постов со стены группы у себя в приложении Android.
Пишу так:

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID,-95640286,VKApiConst.EXTENDED,1,VKApiConst.FIELDS,"text"));
```

Но у меня в приложении выводится список со строками такого типа:

```
com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKApiPost@3c496ce0
```

Почему не выводится текст постов на стене группы?

Когда заменяю строку выше на эту:

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS,"first_name,last_name"));
```

То у меня выводится список строк с именем и фамилией моих друзей.
Вывод строк через ListView осуществляется.

Comment: Вам пришёл экземпляр класса `com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKApiPost`. То, что вы видите в списке - результат вызова его метода `toString`. Очевидно вам надо вытащить текст из этого класса, а не сам класс.

Comment: Добавлю к предыдущему комментарию: посмотрите, какие get* методы доступны у класса com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKApiPost.

В документации указано поле text (http://vkcom.github.io/vk-android-sdk/com/vk/sdk/api/model/VKApiPost.html), возможно, оно имеет public модификатор, и доступно для извлечения. В этом поле содержится текст поста.

Comment: Суть понял, но не понимаю, как вытащить текст. Можете пример сделать, чтобы я уловил?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реализуйте также, как описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525856/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-wall-get-vkapi)

По ссылке организовано получение последних постов и их вывод в консоль.