# Как получить несколько постов при приеме ответа от wall.get() ? (VKApi)

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Выполняю запрос к API Vk.com:

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID,-*моя_группа*,VKApiConst.EXTENDED,1,VKApiConst.COUNT,1,VKApiConst.FIELDS,"text"));
            request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                    VKList<VKApiPost> posts = (VKList<VKApiPost>) response.parsedModel;
                    VKApiPost post = posts.get(0);
                    Log.d("Post:", post.toString());
                    String textpost = post.text;
                    System.out.println(textpost);

                }
```

Выводится в консоль текст одного поста со стены указанной группы. Что нужно сделать, чтобы при изменении:

```
VKApiConst.COUNT,1
```

на:

```
VKApiConst.COUNT,5
```

Выводило все 5 постов ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Может кому пригодится.
Устанавливаем, например, вывод двух последних постов с группы:

```
VKApiConst.COUNT,2
```

И организуем их вывод через цикл:

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
                        VKApiPost post = posts.get(i);
                        String textpost = post.text;
                        System.out.println(textpost);
                    }
```

В консоли у вас будет выведен текст двух последних постов.